# replace old value with new value before render angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input box which is taking input from user. Now I have to add some validation stuff. Like if user enter value which is less than min value then entered value should replace with last entered value. for example

Min value = 10;
if user entered 15 and then 8. So 8 should replace with 15. But I want replace it before 8 render on the page.

I have written the code but it is not working as expected. it is not working when you want replace 10 to any two digit number. I know the issue but dont know the how to fix it.

```
app.directive('exampleDirective1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<input type="text" ng-model="message.msg">',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
       var copy = angular.copy(scope.message.msg);
scope.$watch(function (){return attrs.min}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
       newValue = JSON.parse(newValue);
       oldValue = JSON.parse(oldValue);
  console.log(copy)

console.log(parseInt(newValue.msg) == copy)
           if(parseInt(newValue.msg) < parseInt(copy)){
           console.log('df')
               scope.message.msg = oldValue.msg

    }
                //console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
                //console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
                //do something
            });
          //  console.log(message);                       
        }
    };
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/656/)

Comment: clarify this 1) any default value for the input box ? 2).before rendering means during onload  OR during change in the value ?

Comment: 1) Yes we have default value like 10.
2) before rendering means after validating the value it should render on page

Comment: so we do not allow to type the minimum value?